# Is it absolutely correct that Picasso understands NOT to load if the view has been recycled?

Tags: android, lazy-loading, picasso, async-loading

I'm a little confused: as a rule when async loading images to some sort of list view (whether on Android or iOS or in the abstract on another platform), you essentially must do this ..

```
-- make a note of "which" cell this is (say, #213)
-- start getting the image from the net.
-- it has loaded from the net. What cell are we now?
-- if we are "still" 213, load the image to the image view!
-- if we are "no longer" 213, just forget about it.
```

this is a basic in lazy-loading async images.  For example, Lucas Rocha explains it perfectly in a famous article here:

http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

(scroll down to exactly "Here is just a simplistic sketch of one way you could do it:" ...)

Well now, **as I understand it** Picasso in fact does this for you, completely automatically.

**On its own, Picasso 'knows' if the view has changed.** If the view has changed, **Picasso knows not to bother loading it**

Am I completely correct?  This is a built-in feature of Picasso, and I need do nothing else?

(Aside - I'm somewhat confused "how" Picasso does this; glancing at it I can't see any magic code in Picasso where it makes a note of the id, or something of the holder? view? in question.)

---

Just to be clear, I'm using Picasso in the usual way exactly like this, essentially at the end of getView...

```
Picasso.
  with(State.mainContext).
  load(imageFile.getUrl()).
  placeholder(R.drawable.default).
  noFade().
  into(v.hexaIV);
```

Comment: assumption you are using `Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);` to load image from getView of adapter ... loading into the same imageView(after view is being reused) which didn't finished yet cancels prev downloading ... Piccaso object has 2 maps to store the what action is going on on ImageView(or other target) ... targetToAction  and targetToDeferredRequestCreator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, `Picasso` is that beautiful. You only need that one line inside the getView() method `Picasso.with(c).load(url).into(img);`

how they exactly do it, I'm not sure, but before `Picasso` existed I did my own image loader and it's not so difficult.

Let's say you have a map of Url and ImageView somewhere in your image loader code.

So whenever the code pass `img` to it, it checks against this map, if it is already loading other URL for the same `img` using basic Java `mImg.equals(img)`, if it matches, it knows that, even thou still will cache that URL, it should not deliver the Drawable to the ImageView.

There're a few rare cases that you might want to directly cancel a load, on those cases you can call `Picasso.with(c).cancel(img);`, but that's rare to be necessary.

Comment: Thanks a million for the great answer, @Budius!   (Sorry I was away and didn't "tick" until now.)  Just BTW here's a challenge question for my many Android Expert friends... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747696/implementing-withdelay-in-picasso-android-for-skimming