# Picasso not loading updated image from Web in android

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using Picasso in android app loading image from web url, But I see image is not updated when I updated image on web.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://testServer.com/Images/sponsor.png").into(imageView1);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because picasso has builtin cach so it seems its reading from cashing. try to add Picasso.with(getActivity()).invalidate(file); and tell me what happen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Picasso uses a cache mechanism, so the same image is not re-downloaded twice.

If you need to bypass this cache, you can change [memory](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#memoryPolicy-com.squareup.picasso.MemoryPolicy-com.squareup.picasso.MemoryPolicy...-) or [network](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#networkPolicy-com.squareup.picasso.NetworkPolicy-com.squareup.picasso.NetworkPolicy...-) policy to do this.

Comment: Picasso.with(this)
    .load(url)
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .into(imageView);

Comment: Disabling cache working fine, but taking more time to load. I'm using png images, if I use JPG is there any advantage !? in faster loading ?

Comment: This takes longer because it downloads the image each time. If you just want to invalidate cache to force re-download, you could use @Moudiz's answer

Comment: Thanks, both will re-download image, is there anyway I can make it faster? My main problem is re-downloading images in Grid view. how can I deal with it? I want to load gridview images first then while scrolling up/down it should take from cache. Is there any way?

Comment: How often do your images change? You could do something with the cache to only re-download if the image is from a certain time ago.

Comment: This link is to clear cache http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952627/how-picasso-actually-cache-the-images , now I need a mechanism to get event for everyday to clear cache

Answer (score 4):

Picasso has builtin caching so the image cached automaticly. try invalidating.
example:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).invalidate(file);
```

Comment: @Ashok: try with: Picasso.with(getActivity()).invalidate("file:" + imageFile.getAbsolutePath()); This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
public  void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String image_url,Contextcontext)
{
 try 
  {
    Picasso.with(context)
    .load(image_url)
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_image)
    .into(imageView);
  }

  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    ex.toString();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to download aquery library see here https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading